# Python, ElementTree как заменить содержимое тэга с потомками

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Есть несложный XML, обработка через ElementTree завязана не по имени тэга, а по порядковому номеру его потомка (child[1]). В тэге `<hash>` есть свои потомки `<item>`. Каким образом при обработке удалить их и вписать новые, но чтобы не ломалось оформление. Сейчас оно ломается, следующий тэг `<cnt_out>` записывается в одной строке с `<hash>` (нет перевода строки). Работе не мешает но мешает отладке. Пример XML:

```
<test name="IPV6 D" num="9.1.1" work="1" max_time="300">
    <pcap>9_ipv6.pcap</pcap>
    <hash>
     <item>6be6605550a67d231f7fb23d09ff316095db6314b642a5f8cbc63b74c8236b06</item> 
     <item>99e801cb5360ec777a8f818604998ea9149cd67dd294b895d58532286a578914</item>
    </hash>
    <cnt_out>4</cnt_out>
</test>
```

Пример кода:

```
xml_str = '<hash/>\n\r' # не помогло включение спецсимволов
rt = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
child[1] = rt #затираю имеющийся child[1] - <hash>
new_hash = getNewHash() # функция, возвращающая хэш файла
add_item(child[1], new_hash)

def add_item(child, value): #---------------------------------
    item = ET.SubElement(child,'item')
    item.text = value
```

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree.indent https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, но там касаемо Python 3.9, на более старых версиях сработало это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095434/inserting-newlines-in-xml-file-generated-via-xml-etree-elementtree-in-python